# Perform multiples pivot_longer in a data frame

Tags: r, dplyr, pivot, tidyverse

So this is my data, each row corresponds to a nest and in each row we have 3 chick CHICK_RING1, CHICK_RING2, CHICK_RING3 with their age and body condition.

```
data = wrapr::build_frame(
  "YEAR"  , "Nest"   , "Clutch", "RINGMALE", "RINGFEMALE", "CHICK_RING_1", "CHICK_RING_2", "CHICK_RING_3", "LastAge1", "LastAge2", "LastAge3", "RealMotherAge", "RealFatherAge", "BODYCOND1", "BODYCOND2", "BODYCOND3" |
    "2002", "02-125" , "3"     , "A72"    , "C15"      , "K67"        , "K75"        , "K82"        , "90"      , "90"      , "68"      , "9"            , "14"           , "7.070707" , "9.086538" , "8.622449"  |
    "2008", "08-155" , "3"     , "A72"    , "C15"      , "S09"        , "R30"        , "R40"        , "75"      , "72"      , "73"      , "15"           , "20"           , "7.075472" , "6.984925" , "7.511962"  |
    "2006", "06-267" , "3"     , "A72"    , "C15"      , "O30"        , "O37"        , "O59"        , "73"      , "70"      , "66"      , "13"           , "18"           , "9.227273" , "8.232323" , "9.44186"   |
    "1999", "99-925" , "3"     , "A39"    , "A76"      , "I00"        , "I15"        , "I73"        , "70"      , "69"      , "72"      , "10"           , "10"           , "7.989691" , "7.882883" , "8.043478"  |
    "2011", "11-0305", "3"     , "A66"    , "P48"      , "W25"        , "W30"        , "W46"        , "68"      , "68"      , "68"      , "4"            , "22"           , "7.675676" , "10.4186"  , "7.352941"  )
```

I would like to perform a pivot_longer to have a data frame with 15 rows and in each row the chick ID with their body condition, chick age (lastAge), parents age, year, nest and clutch.

One solution would be to create 3 data sets for each chick  but in prefer something with the tidyverse.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should pivot twice:

```
library(tidyverse)
data %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = all_of(ends_with(c("1","2","3"))), names_to = c("stat", "CHICK_ID"), names_pattern = "(.*)(.)") %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = "stat") %>% 
  mutate(across(-c("Nest", "RINGMALE", "RINGFEMALE", "CHICK_RING_"), as.numeric))
```

The `names_pattern` is a regular expression that will match two groups, each between the parentheses.  The `(.)` will match any single character.  The `(.*)` will match as many characters as it can, while still allowing the `(.)` at the end to capture the last character.

The first pivot_longer will convert most of your data to characters.  You can coerce them back with the `mutate(across(...))`.

Comment: Perfect thanks! And it's a must to convert all the data into characters before pivot_longer if some columns are numeric?